# Use of >> operator

Tags: c++, c++11

Can anyone Please explain me the meaning of the following line in the code

```
 while (ss >> temp)

    std::string str = "123:234:56:91";   

    for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == ':')
           str[i] = ' ';
    }

    vector<int> array;
    stringstream ss(str);
    int temp;
    while (ss >> temp)
       array.push_back(temp);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `ss` is a stream, the `>>` is overloaded to do formatted reading from the stream, depending on the type of the right-hand operand.

So, `while(ss >> temp)` will read white-space separated integers from the `stringstream`. This is why you replace the '`:`' with '' above. When evaluated as a boolean, it will be true if an integer was read and `false` at the end of the stream.

For more details, see for example [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/)